# How to create an empty bytes or bytes32 in ethersjs?

Tags: ethers.js

I have a function that takes a `bytes` in solidity, and I want to pass it an empty bytes string without doing "0x000...", can I do this in ethersjs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ethers.js has a `Constants` object that contains common values. One of those is `ethers.constants.HashZero`, which represents an empty `bytes32` string.

There are more constants that you could read about here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/constants

For `bytes`, you would place an empty array (`[]`) as input in ethers.js. This is due to `bytes` being an array-based value.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted to format a bytes object?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I've updated my answer above to include `bytes`.

Comment: Just to mention, the hex value '0x' should also work for empty bytes.

Comment: @SohamZemse That's correct. A `0x` hex value would also work.

Answer (score 5):

```js
let value = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("")
```

This will give you `0x00....00`

Comment: In Ethers.js V6, `formatBytes32String` was replaced by `encodeBytes32String`.